# Why do I need sticky sessions with a Spring OAuth2 JbdcTokenStore?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to use Spring OAuth2 with a load balancer.
I was thinking that if I use

```
  authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token"
```

I will just need a JdbcTokenStore and am good to go because each spring server has access to the same DB.

But now I am reading in [this github link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jdbc)

```
Even with these (Jbc) services ... needs to be fronted by a load balancer with sticky 
sessions
```

Why do I need Sticky Sessions with a JbdcTokenStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any session-based interaction would need sticky sessions, since the session data is not shared between servers. For example, when you authenticate the user during the authorization code flow, they are authenticated and a session is created. If you weren't using sticky sessions then the authentication information might be lost between browser interactions with the authorization server. The session will be used to cache their initial request while they are logging in, and will also retain the authentication information while the user checks and authorizes the scope requested by the client.

Comment: ok but if I am not relying on session data for example when using grant_type = "password" the user will  use the access_token for all api calls so no session state is needed. thank you for answering

Comment: With the "password" grant type, the only access is from the client to the token endpoint, so there should be no session ID involved. In fact the link you pointed to says that it only applies to the authorization code and implicit grants. Note that the access token isn't used for interactions with the authorization server. It is only used for accessing resources.